# Http API gateway error "too much redirect" and ALB health check move from 200 to 302 after deploying code

Tags: redirect, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-api-gateway, aws-application-load-balancer, http-status-code-302

i have backend server in elastic beanstalk with rds in private subnet, so to access backend i have created http api gateway but problem is when i click on http api gateway endpoint i got error too many redirect.i am facing this problem for last 2 week, applied many solution but no progress,
onething more i oberseved ,when i deployed code on EB then Load balancer health ceck move fromm 200 to 302, and i got  error "health check failed with these code 302",but when i set 302 as health check status code instance become health,but still same error in api  gateway

[curl localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swlNd.png)

also tried to redirect http to https from ALB
and also tried without https 443

```
Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.79.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Server: nginx/1.22.0
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Cache-Control: no-cache, private
< Date: Thu, 12 Jan 2023 11:48:54 GMT
< Location: https://localhost
<
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='https://localhost'" />

        <title>Redirecting to https://localhost</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Redirecting to <a href="https://localhost">https://localhost</a>.
    </body>
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```